# create UITabbarController with UITableViewController xib in xcode 4.3

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitabbarcontroller, uitableview

I'm new in iPhone, I want to create UItabbarController with 4 tabs, each tab contains UItableViewControllers in xib for both iPhone and iPad and want (h & m) files for each table.

Consider that I'm using Xcode 4.3 with iPhone 5.1 and I'm not want to use storyboard.

is there are any good tutorial to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you do not need to create a new UItabbarController.You can use default tabbar controller and what you need is adding 4 tab bar items as UItableViewControllers  to uitabbar  controller.

You can refer to this tutorial about tabbabcontrollers

http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/tabbarcontroller-with-navigationcontroller-and-tableview-in-iphone/

Comment: ok thank you so much. I found also this tutorial now. http://davidbits.blogspot.com/2009/09/iphone-create-uitabbarcontroller.html